# TaskFactory.StartNew or TaskFactory.FromAsync: which one guarantees faster execution of computation-intensive TPL tasks in application?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

If I start computation-intensive TPL task with the button's click from UI, which method will be the best here: **TaskFactory.StartNew** or **TaskFactory.FromAsync**? I'm in need of the following: the task must not hang UI, do its work fast and, in addition, in application can work some other TPL tasks. Time here is the critical demand for speed of work of all tasks run in application. In which case overheads will be less and speed of task execution grows?

Answer (score 3):

The two methods are designed for completely different purposes.

`TaskFactory.StartNew` (or `Task.Run` in .NET 4.5) allows you to fire off some work using a delegate.

`TaskFactory.FromAsync` serves a different purpose.  It's intent is to take a method pair defining an asynchronous method using the [Asynchronous Programming Model (APM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx), and convert it into a `Task<T>`.  This takes an existing asynchronous method and converts it into the new `Task<T>` type, allowing composition with other tasks.

In general, the overhead of running the Task should be small compared to the work being done, especially if the work is "computationally expensive".  I would use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` to start a single task, and the `Parallel` class method (or PLINQ) if you're working on a collection of tasks.

If you're trying to process many work items (far more work items then processing elements/CPU cores on your system), these classes will provide better performance since they will handle the partitioning of work up front to reduce the overhead of the parallelization.

Comment: I have the following situation. I start to develop now an application for trading in stock exchange. One of its main task is to receive trading data from the stock exchange via special gate software library. This process must work continuously during the application execution and I want to realize it as separate TPL task. There are also computation-intensive tasks in application which run periodically but not all at one moment. But their execution times can collide. Is TaskFactory.StartNew will be the best in this situation?

Comment: @user1688773 Potentially.  The continuous processing of input items may work better via a producer/consumer scenario by using something like `BlockingCollection<T>` (with a dedicated Task to process it)

Comment: OK. I'll see. My weakness is that I'm very beginner in TPL. But I bag your pardon - where and when the APM would be useful?

Comment: So where and when in multitask environment the TaskFactory.FromAsync would be useful?

Comment: @user1688773 The APM is for asynchrony, not (necessarily) multitasking